# Assignment of value of one cell to another is not producing the same value in assigment cell

Tags: excel, vba, variables, variable-assignment

I am practicing assigning the value of a cell "1.5" to the value in another cell but it keeps putting 2.0 in the cell instead. Here is the code I'm using.

```
Sub NumberaVariable()

' Declare a Integer Variable, name it "aPrice"
Dim aPrice As Integer
' Have it store the prce information from H3
aPrice = Range("H3").Value
'Paste the price information in C5
Range("C5").Value = aPrice

End Sub
```

I have tried playing with the cell formating and even tested the contencts of H3 by the formula
=+(H3) in cell C5 and it produced the 1.5 expected value. I'm stumped as to why it's adding .5 to the value in cell H3.

Can anyone help me understand why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason of this issue is DataType of your variable. Since you are declaring it as Integer it is changing 1.5(which is a float or decimal value) to 2 (an integer).

You can try defining it as a single using `Dim aPrice As Single`.

Comment: Thank you, I have learned how to do this in Excel. e.g. If cell A1 has a number, say 5, and you want to have cell D5 reflect whatever is in A1, all you have to do is select call D5, and type =A1 and hit enter. I use this method extensively on the job as well as other formulas to sort serial number. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Although this answer was focused on actual codeing method to accomplish my desired result, I went with doing it in excel via formula method. However, I am saving this answer for future use when I am writting code. Very informative. Thank you Ashish Baboo!